Solana finalized transaction not found
I'm using the managed pump portal API and whenever I sell, then try to lookup the transaction it returns an error "not found".
out, err := solanaClient.GetTransaction(
    context.Background(),
    sig,
    &solanaRPC.GetTransactionOpts{
      MaxSupportedTransactionVersion: &transactionVersion,
      Encoding:                       solana.EncodingBase64,
    },
  )

The signature I received does show up on solscan as processed or confirmed but I can't access it through the rpc. I'm using Helius free RPC. I tried waiting 3 minutes between selling and looking up the transaction but no luck.
I also tried checking the signature status:
out, err := solanaClient.GetSignatureStatuses(
    context.Background(),
    false,
    solana.MustSignatureFromBase58(resp.Signature),
)
                    )
if err != nil {panic(err)}
          
fmt.Println(out.Value[0].ConfirmationStatus)
fmt.Println(out.Value[0].Err)


I can look the signature up just fine and it returns "confirmed" and "nil" for the error, yet I still can't look up the transaction itself.
I've been stuck on this for a week or two and I can't figure out what's causing the issue or how to get around it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solscan instantly shows success: https://solscan.io/tx/36iXn9ZTK8HQFtT5j2RzuD8y7FZyZ8fXxXyyx65Qi8D3q6hBjKfPVe6RmS6qfDAojToanFRRQz8JdCU3pTvgMmvj

I had similar issue using the dedicated Solana API.
In my case I realized that the API has some delay in retriving the transaction, so I made a function that calls the API multiple time. usually at the 3rd attempt if the transaction actually was finalized the API responds.
def get_transaction(sig, max_retries=5, retry_delay=15):
client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")
retries = 0
while retries < max_retries:
    try:
        # Make the API request
        response = client.get_transaction(sig, max_supported_transaction_version=0)
        #print(response)
        # Check if the response is not None
        if response.value is not None:
            #print(response.value)
            return response
        else:
            print("Received empty response. Retrying...")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}.")
        raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch transaction after {max_retries} attempts.")
    # Wait before retrying
    retries += 1
    time.sleep(retry_delay)
return response

